# How to measure/estimate the energy consumption of CNN models during testing?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, comparison, pretrained-models

Does someone know a method to estimate / measure the total energy consumption during the test phase of the well-known CNN models? So with a tool or a power meter...

MIT has already a tool to estimate the energy consumption but it only works on AlexNet and GoogleNet, I need something for more Architectures (VGG, MobileNet, ResNet...). And I also need a metric to evaluate the well-known architects in terms of energy consumption. So at first estimate or measure the energy consumption and then evaluate the results with a good metric.

With a measuring device I would measure the power consumption before using the CNN and I will repeat this experiment a few times then I will average the results, and do the same thing while using the CNN and at the end I will compare the results. But I have three problems here:

```
1. how can I know that nothing else is running on the PC that also consumes energy while using the CNN?
2. how can I increase the accuracy of the measurements?
3. I don't find any power meter that measures the energy consumption in short periodes (1s).
```

Thats why I prefer a tool to estimate the energy consumption, the accuracy of the measurments will not be that good but I didn't find any another tool..

Does someone have an Idea, papers, sites that can help me?

Many thanks in advance for your reply!